# Moodle 3.4 How to resize emoticon size 15x15 to 50x50 or 150x150

Tags: php, moodle

I know folder emoticon location is moodle\pix\s. This folder can add new emoticon but I want to resize Big emoticon. How to change pixel of emoticon phpfile. where is phpfile emoticon to solve this. Thankyou